# MySQL procedure to extract a letter from a phrase

Tags: strings, mysql, stored-procedure

**Create a function called GETLYRICS**, which will receive **as parameters a word of at most 15 letters and a number**. It must return the letter of the position **indicated in the number**.

My exercise is fine but is there any other way to do it?

**Here is a link to how the program works :** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/47

```
USE PRUEBA;
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS GETLYRICS$$
CREATE FUNCTION GETLYRICS(letter VARCHAR(15), number INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(1)
BEGIN
    RETURN SUBSTR(letter,number,1);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Hi @Javier-G-Raya consider what happens when number > length of letter, or number is negative.

Comment: I tried it in its day and what happens is that instead of starting at the beginning it starts at the end.

Comment: Meta-commentary: the homework question asking for such a stored procedure is fine, but in reality you shouldn't make a function only for this.

Comment: thanks a lot my friend :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's another interesting way of doing it with `RIGHT` and `LEFT` operators:

```
RIGHT(LEFT(letter,number),1)
```

It first strips the rightmost characters from the letters, then takes the first character from right.

The difference with using `SUBSTRING` or `MID` is that it gets robust to wrong inputs like `-1` (smaller than 0) or `18` (bigger than 15). In the former case it will output NULL, in the latter case it will get the "last" character.

I've used this fiddle to play a bit: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/228.